# findByIdAndUpdate() está criando documento ao invés de atualizar

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express.js, mongoose

Estou fazendo um crud utilizando Node, Express e o MongoDB, porém estou com um problema na operação de update quando utilizo o `findByIdAndUpdate()` do mongoose ele não está atualizando o documento e sim criando um novo.

contactController.js:

```
 module.exports.getEditData = function getEditData(req, res) {
  let  data = {
     id: req.body.id,
     name: req.body.name,
     surname: req.body.surname,
     email: req.body.email,
     phone: req.body.phone
  }

  contactModel.updateContact(data.id, data);

  res.redirect("/contacts");
}
```

contactModel.js:

```
updateContact(id, data) {
    Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {
        name: data.name,
        surname: data.surname,
        email: data.email,
        phone: data.phone
    }, {new: true})
    .then(e => console.log(e));
}
```

Schema:

```
const ContactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name: {type: String, required: true},
 surname: {type: String, require: true},
 email: {type: String, require: true},
 phone: {type: String, require: false}
});
```

Comment: Seu código parece estar correto. Já tentou fazer os testes com `findOneAndUpdate`?

Comment: Esse comportamente de inserir um novo documento se deve ao fato de 1 - Não encontrar o id do documento e 2 - ter o parâmetro `upsert` como `true`, o que, pelo seu código,  não é o seu caso.

Comment: Olá, eu nunca usei essa opção `{new: true}`. Poderia tentar sem ela, ou mesmo colocar {new: false`. Fiz uma pesquisa na documentação do Mongoose, e não achei esse uso. Uma segunda opção, que uso muito, é `Model.findById`, atualiza e salva!

Comment: vc está esquecendo de colocar $set

Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $set: { name: 'jason bourne' }}, options, callback)

Answer (score 0):

Fiz até um test aqui. foi normal. pode ser o id caso não esteja no schema ele não considera. Eu usei o _id

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Types } = mongoose;
// "mongoose": "^6.0.3",
let db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://teste:123456@localhost:27017/teste', {
  maxPoolSize: 50,
  wtimeoutMS: 2500,
  useNewUrlParser: true
});
db = mongoose.connection;
db.once('open', () => {
  console.log('Connection Success.. !');
  return db
});
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  surname: {type: String, require: true},
  email: {type: String, require: true},
  phone: {type: String, require: false}
});

let User = db.model('user', userSchema)

let objnew = {
  
  name:'musta',
  surname: 'fa',
  email: 'musta@uol.com',
  phone: ''
}
let objupdate = {
  name:'terror',
  surname: 'mustafa',
  email: 'mus@gmail.com',
  phone: ''
}
async function run() {
  User.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: Types.ObjectId("612d953d4c86161be1515630") }, objnew, { new: true }).then(e => console.log(e));

  let a = await User.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: Types.ObjectId("612d953d4c86161be1515630") }, { $set: objupdate }, { new: true }).exec();
  console.log('A', a);
}

run()
```